# Arhitecture of Angular 7 online shop

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I created online shop with angular 7 and I am not sure is good architecture. I created 5 modules:

- main module
- products
- shop-cart
- core
- admin

I have `service` :

- admin.service.ts
- products.service.ts
- data-storage-service.ts
- message-data.service.ts
- shop-cart.service.ts

I have module for routing:

- app-routing.module.ts
- products.service.ts

In main module I include all others module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    AdminModule,
    SharedModule,
    ShopCartModule,
    ProductsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ModalModule.forRoot(),

    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    )

  ],
  providers: [,
    InMemoryDataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my core module where I include all `service`:

```
@NgModule({


  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent

  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  providers:[
    DataStorageServiceService,
    ProductsService,
    ShopCartService,
    AdminSerivice,
    MessageService
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

I using `data-storage-service.ts` for communication with server. In my `admin.service.ts` and `products.service.ts` I have methods for  calling method form `data-storage-service.ts`  and store data in list. 
Example:
`data-storage-service.ts` have method :

```
 /** GET Category from the server */
  getCategory(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]>(this.cateogryUrl).pipe(

      catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
    )
  }
```

`admin.service.ts` have method:

```
getCategoryFromServer() {
        this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe((category: CategoryModel[]) => {
            this.categoryList = category;
            this.cateogoryChanged.next(this.categoryList.slice())
        })
    }
```

And in component`admin.componenet.ts` in `ngOnInit` I have

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.admin.getCagegoryFromServer();
  }
```

Are is this correct [image]?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me more logical that the declaration of all services is done in your "main" rather than in "core". It is better to separate as much as possible the dependencies between modules of the same level.

In addition, the module "core" and "shared" are quite close in philosophy, they allow to share basic code in your project. I think that in the future it will be confusing.

Maybe renamed core to "home" or just a part of your application and just use "shared" to share modules.

Then, personally I will pass the definition of routes in the module file.